# Como posso mudar a posição do meu JButton no Swing?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui, awt

Olá, sou novato e bem leigo em Java, estava criando um programa, e nesse programa tinha um botão, eu queria saber como que eu mudo algum botão de lugar no Swing, se alguém pode me ajudar, agradeço :)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class inicio{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tela de incio");
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JButton confirm = new JButton("CONFIRMAR");
        frame.add(painel);
        painel.add(confirm);
        confirm.setBounds(10,10,10,10);
        frame.setVisible(true);


     }

}
```

mesmo quando eu coloco o "setBounds(exemplo, exemplo);" nada acontece
o codigo que usei foi o seguinte

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class inicio{

     public static void main(String[] args){

         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tela de incio");
         JPanel painel = new JPanel();
         JButton confirm = new JButton("CONFIRMAR");
         frame.add(painel);
         painel.add(confirm);
         frame.setLayout(null);
         painel.setLayout(null);
         confirm.setLayout(null);
         confirm.setLocation(50,50);
         frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Coloque o código do que você já tentou na pergunta.

Comment: coloquei, mas até agr so coloquei um botão mesmo;-;

Comment: Nos três componentes (`frame `, `painel` e `confirm `) chame `setLayout(null);` depois de iniciados antes de fazer qualquer operação visual. Para posicionar o botão use `confirm.setLocation(0,0);`

Comment: estou rodando o código e nada aparece na tela

Comment: vou colocar na pergunta como o código ficou e como a tela fica;-;

Comment: Os `setLayout(null);` tem que vir antes de adicionar os componentes. Também coloque isso aqui: `frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));` e isso aqui `frame.pack();` antes de set visible.

Comment: Java Swing tem umas pegadinhas, e a documentação manda deixar para usar `setLayout(null)` só em último caso. É preferível trabalhar com layouts e combiná-los. `FlowLayout`, `BoxLayout`, `BorderLayout` e `GridLayout` por exemplo fazem combinações interessantes, associados ao contêiner genérico `JPanel`. Sugiro ler os tutoriais da Oracle, caso não encontre opção de leitura de boa qualidade em português, e aprenda a mexer principalmente com eles, dentre outros que pode querer aprender.

Answer (score 0):

tente criar as coisas de forma inversa, por exemplo, de dentro pra fora. defina primeiro o botão e suas propriedades (como o local, `setLocation(x,y)`) e depois de todas as suas propriedades setadas então inclua no frame/panel (no seu caso `painel.add(confirm)`)..
os locais x e y definidos no setLocation do button serão usados para definir o local onde ele aparecerá no panel. Lembre-se de dar um `painel.repaint();` no fim.